# Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'fromDate' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic mobile application. One of my modules has this search or filter feature that enables users to input a location or date to be filtered. So, already got the filter code but the problem here is that when i input random letters or words that cannot be found and when i backspace it gives me this TypeError. Cannot read property **fromDate** of undefined. I've been debugging for hours already but i cannot get the right solution. May someone help me debug?

So here's my code when displaying

Comment: You function this.ListofItems() is async? (note:call a function ListofItems and a variable ListOfItem can cause confusion)

Comment: can you add some code?

Comment: where's the code?

Comment: The OP edited out the code?